# Is there any way to access the minus index array element like we do for list in python?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var str=['a','c','d','o','p'];
```

how can I access `'o'` in above string using minus index like str[-2]; in javascript;

In python I easily do this but I got stuck here please help out.

I am working this for this task.
A common modern use is the ROT13 cipher, where the values of the letters are shifted by 13 places. Thus 'A' ↔ 'N', 'B' ↔ 'O' and so on.

so I thought of accessing with minus index. For example if the given letter is z the index is 25 so I access `str[-str.length+13]`;

Comment: Question: Why negative index?

Comment: What is the advantage of accessing elements using negative index?

Comment: i want to access string  beyound the length of string that again starts from index 0 @Sid

Comment: In that case, try `var str=['a','c','d','o','p']; str[ 12 % str.length]`

Comment: can you explain your code.

Comment: In Python, `str[-2]` results in `"o"`. What is the logic behind your desire of "c" to get accessed instead?

Comment: i want it for each and every character for example if the given letter is 'p' , i want +3 index that should give me 'd'

Comment: You can use modulus operator to go around the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is no way to do this but You can create a function in the javascript for the array and then you can like as follows:

```js
str=["a", "c", "d", "o", "p"];

Array.prototype.accessViaIndex=function(index){
if(index<0){
   return this[(this.length+index)]
}
return this[index];
}

console.log(str.accessViaIndex(-1));
```

Comment: I would name the function just `get` and inline the body:
`Array.prototype.get = function(index) {   
   return this[index < 0 ? (this.length + index) : index];   
};`

Comment: Yeah that also we can @A.Chiesa

Answer (score 1):

> i want to access string beyound the length of string that again starts from index 0

JS arrays are not Circular Linked List structure, where if you go beyond bounds, you start with first value.

They are like normal objects where you do not have to specify keys and comes with extensive looping mechanism.

So to achieve this, you will have to use **[modulus operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())**. Idea is to backtrack the index within the bounds.

```js
var str=['a','c','d','o','p'];
var index = 11;

console.log( str[ index % str.length] );
```

Comment: What does the "var index = 11" come from or represent?

Comment: same doubt i too have

Comment: @CertainPerformance OP is looking to have a behavior of a `CirculatLinkedList` where if you have character *z* with index `25` and you go `13` places, you should get a character instead of undefined. So `11` in my example is just a random number that is out of bounds and represents getting proper value even after going above bounds

Comment: Except if you want to reason about the "last one is the -1" you just can't with modulus... You can go __over__ the length and return to 0, but you cannot use negative numbers, which is the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method can do exactly what you're after. It can be passed both positive and negative indexes. When a negative index is supplied, it is treated as an offset from the end of the array, so supplying it with `-2` is the same as indexing the array manually at `array.length-2`:

```js
const arr = ['a','c','d','o','p'];
console.log(arr.at(-1)); // same as: arr[arr.length-1], gives p
console.log(arr.at(-2)); // same as: arr[arr.length-2], gives o
console.log(arr.at(1)); // same as: arr[1], gives c
```

---

Or, for the time being you can take the length minus the index passed through if the value is negative (as shown in Sourabh Somani [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038208/5648954)), here is how a more concise version of that function may look like:

```js
const arr = ['a','c','d','o','p'];
const getElem = (arr, i) => arr[i < 0 ? arr.length+i : i];

console.log(getElem(arr, 3)); // o
console.log(getElem(arr, 0)); // a
console.log(arr); // array is still the same
console.log(getElem(arr, -1)); // p
console.log(getElem(arr, -2)); // o
```

Comment: "You can" usually doesn't imply that you could. You are shallow copying an array (of possibly many items) just to save you from doing `arr[arr.length - 1]` to access the last element. So, please, just don't.